# Login issues with Unity 4.2.1 and Facebook Plugin 4.2.4

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, ios7

I am building the interactive console for iOS7 to test initialization / login / etc.  The app initializes fine, but when I tap the login, it backgrounds the Unity app, goes to a white page for a second, then returns to the Unity app.  When it returns I'm still not logged into Facebook, so the function appears to do nothing.  Anyone experienced problems here?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the log of your facebook plugin - any errors should be described there. Probably there will be something wrong with the plugin settings, or method calling. The correct plugin implementation is available at https://developers.facebook.com/apps